# Best way to deal with multiple Tabs with the same content

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Tabs (from this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation) and I have it setup so that each tab that is created retrieves the same data to allow users to enter multiple records of the same type (i.e. allow the users to enter multiple courses). Once they have completed entering their courses on these different tabs, how I am able to click Save and send the data to another page to add it to the database.

The content of the tab has jQuery/JS and when I start adding more than 1 tab the functionality breaks - I assume it is because of the same variables names? What is the best way to avoid this? By changing .click(function() { events in jQuery to .live('click', function() { ?

Then when it comes to posting the form data to another page to add it to the database, how would you loop over it? Would the  fields have an id on it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities at play here, and it will be hard to give you accurate and comprehensive advice without a code sample. However:

1. You can only have one ID in the page. Even if your tabs are 'hidden', their content is part of the DOM. If you are duplicating ID attributes, you have invalid markup and JavaScript will not be able to target them properly.
2. If you are using classes, a jQuery selector will return an array of objects. In some cases (it depends on function), further chained functions will act only on the first member of the array rather than all members.
3. If new content is being returned via Ajax, then you will indeed need to switch to a delegated listener instead of using `.click()`. You mention `.live()`, but for jQuery 1.7+ this is deprecated; you should be using `.on()` with delegation syntax. The API docs will tell you how to use `.on()` to replace `.live()` with `$(document).on()` but you're better off choosing a closer ancestor... `$('#someContainer').on('click', '.target', function() {});` where #someContainer and .target are just examples... choose a container selector that never gets destroyed, and a valid target selector.

Answer (score 0):

Check for number of tabs and name textbox ids accordingly (txtCourse1, txtCourse2...).
You could get tabs content panels with:

```
$(".ui-widget-content").each(function (){
   $(this).find("input")....
});
```